# How do I bundle a JavaScript module with npm dependencies to have 0 dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a module `module.js` which itself has dependencies.  Some dependencies are local via `require('./relative/import/path.js')` while other dependencies are from npm via `require('npm/import/path.js')`.

My module has it's own exports via `module.exports = { myfunc: myfunc }`.  Other JavaScript files need to `require('./path/to/modules.js')` so they can use myfunc.

How can I bundle together all the dependencies and ship my module as a stand-alone thing?

note: Browserify fails to allow me to export myfunc.

Comment: Webpack might help: https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/

Comment: `note: Browserify fails to allow me to export myfunc.`  You can use the standalone option..

Comment: Please show us how you tried to use browserify, what configuration you used, and what the exact error message was.

Comment: @Keith This worked.  Can you post an answer?