# How do I bundle JavaScript and CSS dependencies locally for offline use?

Tags: javascript, css, deployment, offlineapps, parceljs

Potential similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56740359/how-do-i-bundle-a-javascript-module-with-npm-dependencies-to-have-0-dependencies).

I'd like to build a simple in-browser app that can run without an internet connection.

To develop a Python project, this isn't even a question. You just `pip install whatever` in your favorite virtual env and run offline all day. Your dependency list is also managed for you locally.

While building a toy project with `npm`, I can't figure out how to do the above. [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/getting_started.html) seems like a good tool to build, bundle, minify, etc. But in the end, all dependencies still point to a CDN. I understand this is default behavior, but there seems no way to easily pull all dependencies local and run offline.

Not a web dev so if I'm asking the wrong question, that sort of insight is appreciated also.

Edit: I've already built all the functionality I need. I can run successfully from file:// or a simple http server. What I'm trying to do in consolidate all the dependencies locally so as to not depend on a CDN at runtime. It'd be better to not go to each CDN/GitHub repo, manually download JS/CSS dependencies, and then manually link to them from my code. That's the point of using a bundler or similar. Is Electron or another framework really the best way to do this? For my use that feels like a lot of overhead.

Comment: A web app is a web app (so not offlne). A workaround is creating a PWA (google it) which will cache your code and make your app available offline. Another way, and I think that's what you are looking for, is creating an offline app using electron. see https://www.electronjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can use npm to install and maintain your dependencies. Lets say you are create your project from start. You will need to do the following steps. Assuming you have npm installed.

```
mkdir my-project //create project directory
cd my-project // cd into project direcotry
npm init // init npm project inside the directory.
```

After this you can install javascript packages using `npm i package-name`